# JSLint "Skip on Build" not working in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, jslint

I've been using JSLint on VS 2010 for a while without a problem.  I started using VS 2012 recently and today added the JSLint.VS2012 Nuget package.  The problem is when I right click a script file (e.g. jquery.x.x.js) and choose "Skip on Build", the js file is still parsed by JSLint when I build and I get the usual > thousand warnings. Anyone else experiencing this?
Thanks,
jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved in jslint 1.4.2 released 10/6/2012. [JSLint Release Changelog](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1a417c37-4d6f-43ca-b753-6ea6eb5041fd/view/Discussions/1)

Comment: Here is a link to the [commit](http://jslint4vs2010.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/19158).  Good eye.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is a known issue and was reported to the developers 7 days ago with no response on the Visual Studio Gallery.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1a417c37-4d6f-43ca-b753-6ea6eb5041fd/view/Discussions/1

Two bugs were responded to on the Codeplex, but it does not appear to be high priority:

[1.4.1 "Skip on Build" could not work on Visual Studio Premium 2012](http://jslint4vs2010.codeplex.com/discussions/397812)

[VS 2012 - saving what files to be excluded from build](http://jslint4vs2010.codeplex.com/discussions/397068)

Comment: Resolved in 1.4.2.  Added separate answer to my question to help future searchers. Thanks Anthony.